# inserting a text box at top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying this for a lot of time. How can I add a bigger text box on the top of the page ie it would be outside the div tag of the button which would be clicked
https://jsfiddle.net/Lx3rtLx0/2/
For eg on clicking one of the four emerging images it should display 
a text box on the top of the page like the one shown below

I want the code given to arrive on the page on clicking one of the images. I.e. when you click on one of the images(jsfiddle) ..a text box(code given) should appear. on different clicks diff content.

```css
#adbox {   
            width: 800px;   
            height: 150px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;  
            background-color:grey; 
        }   
        #adbox .adbox1 {   
            width: 200px;   
            height: 50px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;  
            float:left; 
            background-color:lightblue; 
     margin:0px 0px 0px 300px;
            }   
        #adbox .adbox2 {   
            width: 200px;   
            height: 50px;   
            border-width: 0;   
            border-color: red;   
            float:right;
            background-color:red;
           margin:0px 60px 0px 0px;
    }   
    .clear{
         clear:both;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>BOX</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align=center><div id="adbox"> 
<h1><br> xyz sent you a hug</br></h1>
<div class="adbox1"> 
<br>Send a Hug Back</br>
</div> 
<div class="adbox2"> 
<br>Ack | Dis</br>
</div> 
<div class="clear"/>
</div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is requirement to insert `<input type="text">` element at top of document?

Comment: what do you mean to imply

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: see the edit ..i hope that makes it clear

Comment: Are you attempting to insert `.text-box` within `.btn` element above `section` element?

Comment: its something like stacking up the code snippet(the jsfiddle)  on clicking one of the four images (jsfiddle)

Comment: Your HTML is _invalid_. Copy what you've put here in your question and paste it into the W3C's [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input).  Trying to manipulate invalid HTML is [iffy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iffy) at best. Don't use `align=center`, and your `<br>` tags are misused.

Answer (score 0):

Not super clear on your question, do you need to add an input to the jsfiddle in your question? or the code you have listed in your question? If it is in the jsfiddle, just add this to the top of the code:

```
<body>
      <section id="header">
        <div class="inner">
                <div>
                  <input type="text" style="position:absolute; width:300px;" />
                </div>
```

Otherwise, the attribute position:absolute should work out for you, if it isn't in the right place, add attributes like `top:0; left:0`, and that will put your input in the top left despite anything else in your code.

Comment: i want the code given to arrive on the page on clicking one of the images...ie when you click on one of the images(jsfiddle) ..a text box(code given) should appear ...on differant clicks diff content

Answer (score 0):

Simple, on your click button add the code as in https://jsfiddle.net/Lx3rtLx0/6/

```
var input = document.createElement('input'); // if you want label just change inpput to label
input.type='text';
input.value = 'hugs or whatever';
document.body.insertBefore(input, document.body.firstChild);
```

So the full JS become

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".trigger").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("active"); 
    var input = document.createElement('input'); // if you want label just change inpput to label
    input.type='text';
    input.value = 'hugs or whatever';
    document.body.insertBefore(input, document.body.firstChild);
});
```

});

Comment: i dont want it on clicking the main centre picture instead on clicking  on one of the 4 images emerging from it

Comment: and needed the fancy box i made

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Lx3rtLx0/29/ I think it is what you want. You can add whatever you want in there, but the code should allow you to click on one of the images and get something, createElement will allow you to add the fancy box

Comment: kk i had already got till there....but how do i add the fancy box...im not so fluent with javascript

Comment: try https://jsfiddle.net/Lx3rtLx0/40/ There are better fancy boxes like http://jquerymodal.com/ but I tried to stick to javascript as much as possible to show the concept behind it with as little code as possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `data-` attribute on your clickable divs to link them with a specific element (a textbox in this case). For example:

```
<div class="btn btn-icon" title="Send a hug to Mohammed" data-adbox="adbox1">
```

In the click handler, we can retreive this attribute and show the element with id `adbox1`.

Full example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".trigger").click(function() {
        $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    });
    $(".btn.btn-icon").click(function() {
        $('.adbox').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).data('adbox')).show();
    });
    $('.adbox').click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.absolute-center,
.menu,
.menu .btn .fa,
.menu .btn.trigger .line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
.menu {
    width: 5em;
    height: 5em;
}
.menu .btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -10;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s, z-index 0.3s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 2s, z-index 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 2s, z-index 1s, transform 1s;
    transition: opacity 2s, z-index 1s, transform 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.menu .btn.trigger {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    content: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
}
.menu .btn.trigger:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
}
.menu .rotater {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.menu.active .btn-icon {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 50;
}
.rotater:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.menu.active .rotater:nth-child(1) .btn-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(45deg);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align: top;
}
.rotater:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu.active .rotater:nth-child(2) .btn-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-45deg);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align: top;
}
.rotater:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.menu.active .rotater:nth-child(3) .btn-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-135deg);
    transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-135deg);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align: top;
}
.rotater:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.menu.active .rotater:nth-child(4) .btn-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-225deg);
    transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-225deg);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align: top;
}
.menu.active .rotater:nth-child(4) .btn-icon {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-225deg);
    transform: translateY(-12em) rotate(-225deg);
    background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yse7Q.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    align: top;
}
.text-box {
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 30px;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    /* Safari */
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.text-box:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.adbox {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    width: 120px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -70px;
    background: grey;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="header">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="btn trigger">
                <span class="line"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="rotater">
                    <div class="btn btn-icon" title="Send a hug to Mohammed" data-adbox="adbox1">
                        <p class="text-box">
                            Hello
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rotater">
                    <div class="btn btn-icon" title="Send a kiss to Margaret" data-adbox="adbox2">
                        <p class="text-box">
                            This
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rotater">
                    <div class="btn btn-icon" title="Wish Good Morning to your Family" data-adbox="adbox3">
                        <p class="text-box">
                            Doge
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rotater">
                    <div class="btn btn-icon " title="Express your love" data-adbox="adbox4">
                        <p class="text-box">
                            Is
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="adbox" id="adbox1">
    <h1>xyz sent you a hug</h1>
</div>
<div class="adbox" id="adbox2">
    <h1>Send a Hug Back</h1>
</div>
<div class="adbox" id="adbox3">
    <h1>Ack | Dis</h1>
</div>
<div class="adbox" id="adbox4">
</div>
```